# Passing selenium commands inside a list

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Say i have a list , which consist of selenium commands like

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
```

lis = ['browser.find_element_by_id("gbqfba").click()' ,'browser.find_element_by_id("signup_btn_topPanel").click()']

tried to send the commands as,

```
for i in lis:

    driver.i
```

Since i is a string here, python is not accepting it. Any solutions for this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the [exec](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-exec_stmt) command to run strings as python commands:

```
for i in lis:
   exec 'driver.' + i
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

It may be more readable to make a list of dicts and use getattr()

For example:

```
cmd_dict = { 'method' : 'find_element_by_css_selector', 'args' : ('div.btn',) }
method_to_run = getattr( browser, cmd_dict['method'] )
method_to_run( *cmd_dict['args'] )
```